# android: downloadmanager where are the files stored

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am new to using downloadmanager in android. I am using genymotion emulator.

I am trying to download an mp3 file using downloadmanager. I want to know where the file is stored after download.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

it shows /storage/emulated/0. its the shared "external storage"

I also checked

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

it points to `/storage/emulated/0/Download` . The mp3 file in not there.

I also checked /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.simha.sacredindaapp. The mp3 file is not there.

My code for downloading the mp3 file is:

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://audio.iskcondesiretree.com/02_-_ISKCON_Swamis/ISKCON_Swamis_-_R_to_Y/His_Holiness_Radhanath_Swami/Lectures/00_-_Year_wise/Devotional_Nectar_-_2016/2016-01-31_Various_-_Vrindavan_is_Perceived_by_Our_Consciousness-For_Ukraine_Devotees_-_Radhanath_Swami.mp3");
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setDescription("My Download").setTitle("Notification titile");
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set a destination directory.

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://audio.iskcondesiretree.com/02_-_ISKCON_Swamis/ISKCON_Swamis_-_R_to_Y/His_Holiness_Radhanath_Swami/Lectures/00_-_Year_wise/Devotional_Nectar_-_2016/2016-01-31_Various_-_Vrindavan_is_Perceived_by_Our_Consciousness-For_Ukraine_Devotees_-_Radhanath_Swami.mp3");
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setDescription("My Download").setTitle("Notification titile");

// change the name file and your current activity.
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(MainActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "test.jpg");

downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: That means if we dont set the destination directory, we dont know where its being downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

As Lior Shitrit mentioned, you need to set destination directory using: `requet.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(...);`.

To get downloaded file uri you need to register `BroadcastReceiver` with `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` action. Next, in `onReceive` if action equals `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` you can get unique download ID and using it query for status and local uri:

```
String action = intent.getAction();
if (action.equals(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)) {
    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
    Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId));
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
        String uriString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
        ...
    }

    cursor.close();
}
```